# Check array and if one value missing every 2 elements

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have and array from string.
When I get the values from string then I split the string so I get an array.

If I give in command:

```
.command 12 Test 1 Test1 2 Test3 and so on
```

Then I get: `['12', 'Test', '1', 'Test1', '2', 'Test3']`

This is good but I don't know how to check 12, 1, 2 if it is integer or normal text and if after the numbers someone gave text too or not.
Of course I could do in If statement but it would be long code then.

- So I need check first value is number or not
- I need check if the first value given then the member gave to bot a text too or not.
- Third value if it is number or not
- Fourth value given or not if the number given
- And so on.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will check you the first number if it's a number or not. If yes then it will check the next value if it's a string or not. I hope it helps.**

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i += 2) { 
  if (isNaN(result[i])) {
    // not a number
  } else {
    if (typeof result[i+1] == 'string') { // 2nd value is a text }
    else { // 2nd value not a string }
  }
}
```